# Furtwangler's Principal ideal theorem in number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Does anyone know a simple proof, using cohomological method of the fact that the verlagerung from a finite group G. to its commutator subgroup G', i.e. $$G/G'->(G')^{ab}$$ vanishes?
The simplest proof I know appears in Witt, Proc. International Congress of Mathematicians, Amsterdam, 1954, Vol 2, pp71–73.
The main Lemma there can be easily restated by cohomolological means, as describing the Verlagerung map, as $$res_{-2}:H_1(G,Z)=H_T^{-2}(G,Z)\rightarrow H_T^{-2}(H,Z)=H_1(H,Z)$$
and using dimension shifting to reinterpret it as $$res_{-1}:H_T^{-1}(G,I_G)\rightarrow H_T^{-1}(H,I_G).$$
However, I was not able to prove the theorem purely in cohomological means.
Will appreciate any other refereneces or ideas.